# Meaning of a Expression

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was trying to solve a mathematical question in partial differential equation. 
The question was,
Find the integral surface of the partial differential equation

$$(x + y − z)p − (y + x + z)q = 2z$$

Here $p = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} $ ; $q = \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} $

which passes through the curve $z(x, x) = 1$.

My question is what does $z(x, x) = 1$ mean.
Does it mean a surface $z(x,y) = 1 $ where also $y = x$.
Can someone give me clue about the expression.

Thanks

ANupam

Comment: What are $p$ and $q$? This doesn't look like a DE without more explanation...

Comment: @MPW: I believe that this is a somewhat standard notation in some parts of the world: $p = \frac {\partial z} {\partial x}$ and $q = \frac {\partial z} {\partial y}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A late answer ( consistant with doraemonpaul's answer) :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dz}{dt}=2z$ , letting $z(0)=1$ , we have $z=e^{2t}$

$\therefore\begin{cases}\dfrac{dx}{dt}=x+y-e^{2t}~......(1)\\\dfrac{dy}{dt}=-x-y-e^{2t}~......(2)\end{cases}$

$(1)+(2)$ :

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}+\dfrac{dy}{dt}=-2e^{2t}$

$\dfrac{d(x+y)}{dt}=-2e^{2t}$

$x+y=C_1-e^{2t}$

$\therefore\dfrac{dy}{dt}=-C_1$

$y=C_2-C_1t$

$\therefore-C_1=-x-C_2+C_1t-e^{2t}$

$x=C_1-C_2+C_1t-e^{2t}$

$\therefore\begin{cases}x=C_1-C_2+C_1t-e^{2t}\\y=C_2-C_1t\end{cases}$

$x(0)=f(y_0)$ , $y(0)=y_0$ :

$\begin{cases}C_1-C_2=f(y_0)\\C_2=y_0\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}C_1=y_0+f(y_0)\\C_2=y_0\end{cases}$

$\therefore\begin{cases}x=y_0+f(y_0)-y_0+(y_0+f(y_0))t-e^{2t}\\y=y_0-(y_0+f(y_0))t\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}x=y_0t+f(y_0)(t+1)-e^{2t}\\y=y_0(1-t)-f(y_0)t\end{cases}$

$\therefore\begin{cases}y_0=(x+y+e^{2t})t+y=\dfrac{(x+y+z)\ln z}{2}+y\\f(y_0)=x-(x+y+e^{2t})t+e^{2t}=x+z-\dfrac{(x+y+z)\ln z}{2}\end{cases}$

Hence $x+z-\dfrac{(x+y+z)\ln z}{2}=f\left(\dfrac{(x+y+z)\ln z}{2}+y\right)$

$z(x,x)=1$ :

$f(x)=x+1$

$\therefore x+z-\dfrac{(x+y+z)\ln z}{2}=\dfrac{(x+y+z)\ln z}{2}+y+1$

$(x+y+z)\ln z=x-y+z-1$

Answer (score 0):

While it is not easy to tell from what you give us, it seems that the solution $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, therefore its graph in $\Bbb R^3$ is a smooth surface (parametrized by $x$ and $y$). There are many such solutions of that equation, so you are required to find only the one containing the parametrized curve $x \mapsto \big( x,x,z(x,x) \big)$ with all the points having the $z$ coordinate equal to $1$, so the curve is $x \mapsto (x,x,1)$ - which is a straight line at constant height $1$. (This plays the role of boundary condition, allowing you probably to obtain a unique solution.)